# Item referenced in row increase by column not row

Tags: excel

I am trying to make it so that the item I am referencing in one row (ex. =(example!A1) ) is increasing by the column not the row when I am dragging the cell down several rows (example A1, B1, C1, D1 .. not A1, A2, A3, A4).

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(example!$1:$1,ROW(1:1))
```